# VS2015 crash while deploy windows phone 8 app to emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015

VS2015 crash, while Run app with Windows Phone emulator, I tried with Phone 8.1 and Windows 10 Mobile Emulator. Emulator launch successfully but VS can't deploy app, end crash.

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.23107.0, time
>   stamp: 0x559b7ead
>       Faulting module name: SirepClient.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x559f6024
>       Exception code: 0xc0000005
>       Fault offset: 0x0002c376
>       Faulting process id: 0x3770
>       Faulting application start time: 0x01d123ea21bcb890
>       Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>       Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Phone Sirep\8.1\SirepClient.dll
>       Report Id: d583c604-2aed-41b5-ac84-8223f613cef0
>       Faulting package full name:
>       Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> ---
>
> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.AccessViolationException    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop.ConManServerClass.ConnectDevice()
>   at Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Device.Connect()    at
>   Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Wrapper.ConnectivityWrapper12.CreateConnectedDeviceInstance(Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Device)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SmartDevice.MultiTargeting.Connectivity.ConnectableDevice.Connect(Boolean)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonProject.SmartDevice.Deploy.DeployTask.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.SilverlightMobileVSProjectFlavorCfg.Deploy(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Answer (score 2):

This solved my Windows Phone 8.1 Deploy to Device Visual Studio 2015 crash issue:

1) Shut down Visual Studio.

2) After enabling/unlocking your device (WinPhone 8.)1 for development;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508

Make sure you download and install the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk

3) After installing this SDK, try to connect to your WinPhone 8.1 through the SDK, which will trigger a "Special Update" for that device.

4) After installing the update on your device and it reboots, start Visual Studio and deploy/debug to your device.

Comment: What do you mean by connecting to the phone through the SDK? To which application are you specifically referring to?

Comment: To trigger the update I mentioned to the Windows 8.1 device, a connection must be through the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK 1st and not through VS.

Comment: As @aaaabcv says in his answer, I think the application you're referring to is 'Windows Phone Developer Power Tools 8.1'. There isn't actually an application named 'Windows Phone 8.1 SDK', as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred to me a few months ago and to resolved I have to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK, because the Visual Studio 2015 only installs the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on the previous post to give the answer about the "SDK tool".

But the tool he means is actually the Windows Phone Developer Power Tools. If you connect, it will trigger an update installing the powertools runtime on the device.

Interestingly I ran into that problem after first being successful with deploying to the phone. But after I restarted Visual Studio, I got the deployment crash.

Unfortunately it did not resolve the problem for me.